# Stable, tame A-infinity isomorphism?

Tags: homological-algebra, knot-theory

Linear duality provides a correspondence between differentials on free tensor algebras and A-infinity algebras.  Under this correspondence, what is the A-infinity counterpart of "stable, tame isomorphism" of dgas, a notion prevalent in Legendrian knot theory?

(I recall that "tame" refers to an automorphism which shifts a single generator by a combination of other generators -- or the composition thereof -- while "stable" means up to adding some pairs of generators a and b obeying da=b.)

Comment: Aw, c'mon, I thought all those dg's and A-infinities would surely get the MO crowd out!  As a further enticement for people to comment without full knowledge of the answer, let me confess that I had to edit my post several times before getting the definition of "tame" even reasonably accurate.

Comment: Well, stabilizing corresponds to taking the direct sum with the $A_\infty$ (co)algebra which is the linear span of those two new generators and which has all (co)products zero except that differential.

Comment: Thanks, Gabriel.  Stabilization is clearer, but tameness?  The actual definition of "stably tame isomorphic" is tamely isomorphic after possibly stabilizing one or both dgas.

Comment: If I'm doing things right, a tame isomorphism is a "strict" isomorphism of $A_\infty$ (co)algebras, meaning a morphism $(f_1,f_2,\ldots)$ where $f_1$ is an isomorphism and $f_i$ is zero for $i>1$. It's not clear to me whether every strict isomorphism arises as a tame isomorphism, that's a question about linear algebra. What changes of basis of a linear space can you make with compositions of these automorphisms that shift a generator by a combination of other generators?

Comment: I guess the best you could hope for is the whole special linear group?

Comment: Okay fine, yes, these generate $SL$. Then I claim a tame automorphism of $V$ is a strict $A_\infty$ automorphism with $f_1$ in $SL(V)$. This still doesn't say anything about what stable tame would *mean* in $A_\infty$ land.

Comment: Thanks -- can you turn your comments into an answer, and do elaborate!  As bonus/incentive, I'll comment on how the notion arises.  To a Legendrian knot Chekanov and Eliashberg define a differential graded algebra.  Isotoping the knot changes the projection by a sequence of Reidemeister moves.  Doing just one such move (for example, Reidemeister II) can add (say) a pair of generators to the algebra (corresponding to crossings) as well as a differential connecting them (and possibly others):  this produces a stably tame isomorphic algebra.  See, e.g., http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9709233.pdf

Comment: I have heard the setup before but had never looked at the paper. It looks like i misinterpreted the meaning of your phrase "combination of other generators." So it'll take a little more work. If I can say something intelligible using the right definition, I will make it into an answer if no one beats me to the punch.